# How to use S3 with signature V2 In Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, flysystem

I have a project in Laravel 7 and I want to use a compatible storage S3 who accept only version 2 of signature. I tried to install flysystem/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 but there are more conflict with Symfony and Guzzle. Is there a method for use flysystem/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 with signature v2?

Thanks

Comment: what are the conflicts, in flysystem

Comment: what is the issue with using https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel